# Notification area crashes on launch - Ubuntu Mate 18.04.1

Tags: ubuntu-mate, notification-area

on Ubuntu Mate, the notification area crashes on launch.  I am given the option to relaunch, which I do and then it's fine.  Any ideas?  Many thanks, David

Comment: Is there an error, and if yes, then what is it? Otherwise, how do you know it crashes?

Comment: Try to ask this question on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: A  box pops up telling me it has crashed, also no icons where they would be expected - no other information but gives me options to leave closed or to relaunch, or words to that effect.  Once relaunched, all is fine.